# Артефакты на поверхности после запекания света

Tags: unity3d

После запекания света на объектах с дефолтным мэшем(куб и объекты ProBuilder) появляются артефакты. Lightmapper стоит GPU, с CPU та же тема.[image: артефакты]

[image: настройки]

Какие есть варианты по решению данной проблемы?